# Linear algebra: Proof of number of solutions in a linear system. What is going on?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my linear algebra book I see this:

[image]

I am confused as to why the nonzero column matrix of $x_b = x_1 - x_2$ is a solution but not the zero one? I am also confused as to why $A(x_1 - x_2) = O$

For context, I just read the passage below and I see how the column matrices don't have to be zero matrices to be a solution to the equation $Ax = 0$:

[image]

For example, the matrix:

$$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   1\\
   4\\
   7\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

is a non zero matrix but is a solution to the above example. But in the proof at the beginning, why does $A(x_1 - x_2) = 0$ and why is the nonzero column matrix a solution to the homogeneous system of linear equations Ax = 0? I might need an example to elucidate this concept. How do you know the column matrix is non zero?

Lastly, what is the proof doing?

BTW, I understand homogeneous to mean:

[image]

Comment: It states that $x_{1}$ & $x_{2}$ are distinct solutions, which means $x_{1} \neq x_{2}$.  Thus, $x_{b} = x_{1}-x_{2} \neq 0$

Comment: Use linearity to compute $A(x_1-x_2)$.

Comment: Oh I see, it's a nonzero solution because we assume they are two different solutions. got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both solutions to $Ax=b$ we get $$A(x_1 -x_2) = Ax_1 -Ax_2 = b-b =0$$ So $x_h=x_1-x_2$ is a solution to $Ax=0.$

Since $x_1\ne x_2$  we get $x_h=x_1-x_2 \ne 0$

Answer (score 3):

Solutions of nonhomogeneous equations have the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix} {\rm any \; solution \;of} \\ {Ax=b} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} {\rm another \; solution \;of} \\ {Ax=b} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} {\rm some \; solution \;of} \\ {Ax=0} \end{bmatrix}.
$$

It means that you can desribe *all of them* by knowing only *one of them* + how the solutions of the corresponding homogeneous equation look like.

**Example.**
Let us look at the following equation:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 10 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}
$$

It has many solutions. For example,

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}, \quad \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 10 \end{bmatrix}, \quad \begin{bmatrix} x_3 \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -200 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

But what is the *structure* of these solutions? One can see that they all have the form

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_n \\ y_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ d \end{bmatrix}.
$$

It turns out (and your book gives you a proof!) that the second term $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ d \end{bmatrix}$ is the common form of all the solutions of the corresponding homogeneous equation

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

So you can obtain any solution of the nonhomogeneous equation by taking any particular one of its solutions ($\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$) and adding some solution of the homogeneous one ($\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 10 \end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -200 \end{bmatrix}$).

If this answer is not enough, please ask more precisely.

Comment: I am confused as to why the nonzero column matrix of xb=x1−x2 is a solution but not the zero one? I am also confused as to why A(x1−x2)=O

Comment: @Jwan622, equation $0 \cdot x = 0$ has a zero solution and a non-zero solution. Equation $1 \cdot x = 0$ has only zero solution.  Equation $0 \cdot x = 1$ has no solution at all. Of course, $x_b$ may be zero (if $x_1=x_2$), but if $x_1 \neq x_2$, it is not.